# Google custom search using multiple search labels - refinements?

Tags: google-custom-search

With google custom search, one can refine results to a label by using the more: operator like so:

```
searchterm more:blog
```

But how can one restrict results to more than one label?  It seems like this should work:

```
searchterm more:blog,articles
```

.. but it does not appear to - instead it is ignored as if I had specified an invalid label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my research, you cannot use the `more:` operator in a Google query string for the following reasons:

First, [Google Custom search documentation on search refinement never provides a query string example](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/refinements). Also, [custom search is performed via APIs and XML requests not via a straight query](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/dev_guide).

Secondly, sites that detail (examples below) how to customize a Google query string don't contain examples with the `more:` tag. So, I don't think it's possible to create labels using the `more:` operator.

- http://jwebnet.net/advancedgooglesearch.html
- http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#Search_options
- http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=adv_operators&answer=136861

Another find from [Automatic refinements](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70346).

> Your second option is to append the `more:` operator (followed by the
>   label name) automatically to your users' queries in order to trigger
>   one of your labels. You can do this by altering the search form from
>   which users submit their queries.

So, the use of the `more:` operator is possible but only referencing labels you have already created.

---

**UPDATE**

Also, I recommend using Google's site to [Test and troubleshoot your Linked CSE](http://www.google.com/cse/tools/cref).  You can [define your own context for a search engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/context?hl=en) and accomplish your requirements.

```
<Facet>
    <FacetItem title="Blogs">
        <Label name="more:blog" mode="FILTER" weight="0.8">
        </Label>
    </FacetItem>
</Facet>
<Facet>
    <FacetItem title="Articles">
        <Label name="more:articles" mode="FILTER" weight="0.8">
        </Label>
    </FacetItem>
</Facet>
```

Here are some more resources:

- http://www.google.com/cse/ - Google has a wizard to help create and customize the search
- [Google Help articles › Learn more › Search results > Refinements](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=11498&parent=&ctx=topic)
- From the [Developer's Guide: Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/start#refinements) page:

  > **Refinements**
  >
  > Refinements are a way for you to categorize sites by topics. For
  >   example, if you have a bicycling search engine, you can have
  >   categories of, say, bike maintenance, bike reviews, bike stores,
  >   biking skills, and so on and so forth. You can create refinement
  >   labels that you associate with the sites you listed in the Sites tab.
  >   The refinement links appear at the top of your search results page,
  >   and users can click them to narrow down their searches. A search page
  >   can have as many as 16 refinement links.
  >
  > To create a refinement label, click **Add Refinement**, and define the
  >   settings. To tag websites with labels, go to the Sites tab, select
  >   check boxes next to the sites, and select the label from the **Label
  >   actions** drop-down list. You can tag sites with more than one label.
  >
  > Before you create your labels, you might want to check out [existing
  >   labels](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ref_prebuiltlabels) and pool your resources with Google and other users.
- If you want to filter the results via the API, the [Programmer's Guide: Filtering and sorting search results](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search) has everything you need.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem and/or answer your question?

Comment: I suppose it does answer the question - the answer being "no, it's not possible."  Thanks for the additional links/details, I had those already, but they may help the next person.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, what you're looking for isn't possible. It's possible with pre-existing labels but not random words appended at the end of the query. I think this merits an accepted answer.

Comment: I don't have time now, but I will spend some time trying what you say about defining my own context.  These are defined labels I'm talking about, not just random words, so I hope that will do it.

Comment: You can restrict to more than one label. This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14045239/1085891. And this won't require creating a context. Just create the two labels and apply them to your custom search.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to search in many refinements label.
While it's not possible to add several "more" parameters, we can add several "less" parameters in the query.

Let's say we have these refinements labels defined: 
**blogs, articles, news, documents**

doing **+more:blogs +more:articles** will fail.

BUT **+less:news +less:documents** will do the work and find only results in blogs and articles!

So it's possible to play with the less parameter and get only the categories you want ;)

Only strange is that actually the less parameter seems not to be in the google API documentation...
I would be glad to have your feedback when its working for you